# Python - Assigning (x, y) coordinates to values of list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix, coordinates

I have a 3x3 matrix in the format

```
matrix= [[0, 1, 2],
         [3, 4, 5],
         [6, 7, 8]]
```

I want to define a function that will transform any given list of lists into the following format where there is 1. the value and 2. the (x,y) coordinates corresponding to each value

**(0,0) (0,1) (0,2)**

**(1,0) (1,1) (1,2)**

**(2,0) (2,1) (2,2)**

So for example

```
input = [[0, 1, 2],
         [3, 4, 5],
         [6, 7, 8]]
```

will become

```
output =[(0, (0, 0)), (1, (0, 1)), (2, (0, 2)),
         (3, (1, 0)), (4, (1, 1)), (5, (1, 2)),
         (6, (2, 0)), (7, (2, 1)), (8, (2, 2))]
```

Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: How do you try to solve this?

Comment: I echo the above point: What have you tried so far. And more importantly, why?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 2],
          [3, 4, 5],
          [6, 7, 8]]

out=[(v,(i,j) for i,lst in enumerate(matrix) for j,v in enumerate(lst)]
# [(0, (0, 0)), (1, (0, 1)), (2, (0, 2)), 
#  (3, (1, 0)), (4, (1, 1)), (5, (1, 2)), 
#  (6, (2, 0)), (7, (2, 1)), (8, (2, 2))]
```

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your problem:

```
matrix      = [[0, 1, 2],
                   [3, 4, 5],
                   [6, 7, 8]]
transformed_matrix = []
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        transformed_matrix.append((matrix[i][j],(i,j) ))
print(transformed_matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to know here is basic knowledge of loops and nested loops and Array.

This will solve help you

```
matrix =      [[0, 1, 2],
               [3, 4, 5],
               [6, 7, 8]]
result = []
k = 0 #this k is because in your output you want to increment it by 1 after every iteration
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix)):
        count = (k, (i, j))
        k = k + 1
        result.append(count)

print(result)
```

If you are beginners just check out some of these website for knowledge. But you will not find direct answer or exact logic for this question. links are only for study purpose and if you already know these topic you can ignore it.

[Loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm)
[Array](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp)